# Movie about a diver that finds and raises creature after being attacked in the ocean

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

So this movie starts off with an expedition to really deep in the sea. The diver/scientist lady gets attacked in the depths by something kinda resembling a giant black squid. After she's pulled back up and is looking through the damaged equipment (she was also fired from the diving project) she finds an egg.

She takes the egg and puts it in an aquarium in her basement. It hatches into a squid creature. She finds out it drinks blood and so gives it blood. Her and the creature like bond and she ends up feeding her boyfriend and sister to it. But the guy who hired her for the dive set the dive to find this creature, so she finds out it's like a sacred monster thing.

In the end it's put back into the ocean and multiplies. Ends on a scene of the ocean with tentacles. Saw it recently.

Comment: Ah yes, girl meets squid, girl feeds squid blood, girl releases squid. It's a story as old as time.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Comment: Sounds like Little Aquarium of Horrors.

Answer (score 10):

Could this be [The Creature Below](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt4368098/)?

> The marine biologist Olive Crown (Anna Dawson) applies to the research
>   of Dr. Fletcher (Zacharee Lee) in deep waters and is hired. However
>   Olive is attacked by a huge creature that damages her underwater
>   equipment and she has amnesia with the trauma. Dr. Fletcher fires
>   Olive and she finds an egg in the equipment and she brings it home.
>   She leaves the egg in the basement of her house, and soon the egg
>   hatches and Olive captures the offspring to study. She tries every
>   type of fish to feed the creature but none satisfies it. Olive finds
>   that the creature feeds only with her blood. Soon Olive kills people
>   to feed the creature. Meanwhile her boyfriend Matthew "Matt" Gardiner
>   (Daniel Thrace) realizes that his girlfriend is changing her behavior,
>   but he does not suspect that she is feeding the creature with blood
>   from her victims. When Olive's sister Ellie Crown (Michaela Longden)
>   comes to her house to spend a couple of days, she finds that something
>   is wrong with Olive and snoops around the basement with tragic
>   consequences.

Warning. Trailer is NSFW (gory!)